# An "issue" after ppa:ondrej/php5 deprecation

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, ssh

Today I was upgrading PHP 5.5 on my LEMP stack to version 5.5.35. After upgrading I received an on-screen message that the repo **ppa:ondrej/php5** is deprecated and if I want to continue receiving php updates I should move onto **ppa:ondrej/php** which now includes PHP 5.5, PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0 in [one place](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5). Previously these versions were in different repos.

I followed Ondřej's advice and I run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade --show-upgraded
```

All went fine, except that two packages were held back: **php-pear** and **pkg-php-tools**. That of course happens from time to time when package dependencies change so I run:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear pkg-php-tools
```

Then, I got a message that additionaly the following packages will be installed:

```
php-cli php-common php-xml php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-json php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline php7.0-xml
```

Immediately I felt that something is wrong here. Why the hell I need PHP 7.0 packages when I'm running PHP 5.5? However I went with option YES and apparently everything went fine. The server is running, no errors or confilcts that I'm aware of. Then I was curious and I checked what version of PHP am I running?

```
php -v
```

The output was:

```
PHP 7.0.6-1+donate.sury.org~trusty...
```

What the hell happened here? How did I ended up installing PHP 7.0 and why the server/site isn't crashing? Since I use nginx with php-fpm, by examining the nginx.conf I can clearly see that nginx is pointing to php5-fpm.sock so I definitely run php5-fpm here. Plus the site is up, and there are no PHP errors in the log.

I also went and I've uploaded a **phpinfo** file. The file shows I'm using PHP 5.5.35. So there are two conflicting messages where command via ssh shows that the PHP version is 7.0.6, while the phpinfo file shows that the server is using PHP 5.5.35.

So I run:

```
sudo apt-get remove php7.0-common
```

All previously added php7.0 packages were removed and also those two that were initially being held back.

Now, after checking the PHP version via SSH it showed correctly 5.5.35. While all this was happening the server had no trouble whatsoever. The status at this moment is that I don't have **php-pear** and **pkg-php-tools** packages, but if I try to install them all those php7.0 packages will have to be installed too.

I've also examined **/etc/php5** and **/etc/php** folders. In this second folder there is **7.0** folder where **cli** and **mods-available** folders with mods inside reside.

Can someone explain to me what is happening here and what should I do? Are php5 and php7.0 simultaneously running on the server? Do I need those two packages that were held back in LEMP + Wordpress stack?

Comment: Most likely `/usr/bin/php` points to php7.0-cli

Comment: On my debian server `/usr/bin/php` points to `/etc/alternatives/php` which points to `/usr/bin/php7.0` (yes I run PHP 5.6 and 7.0 simultaneously). The symlinks might be the same on your server.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and `/etc/alternatives/php` points to `/usr/bin/php5`.

Comment: It means that the cli-version is updated, but `php-fpm` version not changed. cli and fpm - packages has different executables. They don't run simultaneously it's simple two different packages.

Comment: Yes, right, I assumed that, but:

1. How's that possible?
2. Why phpinfo file and ssh command show different outputs?
3. Why there's still a `/etc/php/7.0` folder at all with modules inside?
4. Are `php-pear` and `pkg-php-tools` packages essential for LEMP+Wordress stack?

Comment: If you asked that on askubuntu.com where it belongs, I would have noticed your question earlier.

Answer (score 1):

`php-pear` and `pkg-php-tools` must depend on PHP CLI for default PHP version and that's PHP 7.0.  Installing `php-cli` pulls `php7.0-cli` that will install `/usr/bin/php7.0` and registers it as alternative with highest (`70`) priority to provide `/usr/bin/php`.

Installing PHP CLI binary is mostly harmless unless you need to run PHP scripts locally using command line.  I could recommend two approaches:

1. Rewriting those scripts to specify required version, e.g. changing `php <script>` to `php5.6 <script>`, or
2. Use `update-alternatives` to switch `/usr/bin/php` to your desired PHP version: a) switch to specific version `update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6` or b) `update-alternatives --config php` configure the version by hand

More thorough version of the migration guide is located in [DEB.SURY.ORG Wiki](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/wiki/PPA-migration-to-ppa:ondrej-php).

To use the new PHP FPM packages, you need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.5-fpm # for PHP 5.5
sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm # for PHP 5.6
sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm # for PHP 7.0
```

and adjust the socket accordingly, look into default FPM configuration:

```
sudo editor /etc/php/X.Y/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

for the socket location (it's `/run/php/phpX.Y-fpm.sock` by default).

Comment: Thank you. However I've wiped out PHP altogether following [this tutorial on askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59886/how-to-compelety-remove-php/187278#187278) and I've installed fresh PHP 7.0. I would have had to upgrade soon anyways so I went and took the jump.